# Weak Polymorphism in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, ml, value-restriction

I am a little confused about weak polymorphism in *OCaml*.

Please see the following snippet, where I define a function `remember`:

```
let remember x =
   let cache = ref None in
      match !cache with
       | Some y -> y
       | None -> cache := Some x; x
;;
```

The compiler can infer the polymorphic type `'a -> 'a`, and `cache` is used locally.

But when I modify the above code into

```
let remember =
   let cache = ref None in
    (fun x ->  match !cache with
         | Some y -> y
         | None -> cache := Some x; x)
;;
```

the compiler infers the weakly polymorphic type `'_a -> '_a`, also, it seems that `cache` is shared across invocations of `remember`.

Why does the compiler infer a weakly polymorphic type here and why is `cache` shared?

What is more, if I change the code again

```
let remember x =
   let cache = ref None in
    (fun z ->  match !cache with
         | Some y -> z
         | None -> cache := Some x; x)
;;
```

the compiler infers the polymorphic type `'a -> 'a -> 'a` and `cache` becomes locally used. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
let remember =
 let cache = ref None in
  (fun x ->  match !cache with
       | Some y -> y
       | None -> cache := Some x; x)
;;
```

Here `cache` is closed over by the returned function. But at the point where we declare `cache`, we have no information on what the type will be; it'll be determined by whatever the type of `x` is and `cache` is created when `remember` is defined.

But since this is a closure we can do something like this:

```
> remember 1
  1
```

Now it's clear that `cache : int option ref` since we've actually stored something in it. Since there's only ever one `cache`, `remember` can only ever store one type.

In the next one, you close over 2 things, `x` and `cache`. Since we create a new `cache` ref with each invocation of `remember` the type can be fully polymorphic again. The reason the type isn't weakly polymorphic is because we know that we're going to store `x` in it and we have `x`s type at the time when `cache` is created.

Comment: I guess that you meant that `cache` has type `int option ref` and not `ref (None int)`.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to do with value restriction. Full value restriction (as in SML) would reject your code altogether. Weakly polymorphic types are described in the paper "Relaxing the Value Restriction" by Jacques Garrigue, which I admittedly just stumbled upon after reading your question:

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/garrigue-value_restriction-fiwflp04.pdf

The fact that `cache` is shared across invocations should be obvious if you have a correct mental model of what ML code means.  You are defining two values, `remember` and `cache`. Nesting simply makes the scope of `cache` private to the block.

Answer (score 1):

```
let remember x =
   let cache = ref None in
      match !cache with
       | Some y -> y
       | None -> cache := Some x; x


let remember x =
   let cache = ref None in
    (fun z ->  match !cache with
         | Some y -> z
         | None -> cache := Some x; x)
```

In the above two versions, `remember` is a "direct" function, every time you call it like `remember 1`, it will initialise `cache` to `ref None`, isn't it? So actually, it does not remember anything, the `cache` is not shared between any `remember` calls.

---

In the other version:

```
let remember =
   let cache = ref None in
    (fun x ->  match !cache with
         | Some y -> y
         | None -> cache := Some x; x)
```

it is different. `remember` is still a function for sure, however, the real part that defines its content is `(fun x -> match ...)`. It includes `cache` and cache is initialised once and will be only once. So `cache` is shared between the future `remember` call.

Comment: Your 'other version' just solves the code that kept me thinking most of yesterday's afternoon!